# How to Match Stripe Transfers to Payouts Using Balance Transaction API?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm building a finance app that uses Stripe to make transfers to accounts and handle manual payouts. My goal is to match each transfer to its corresponding payout to keep our records straight and give detailed reports to our users. Stripe provides information on both transfers and payouts through balance transaction data, but it's not straightforward to figure out how transfers are included in a payout since a payout combines many transfers and other financial adjustments.

Here's a simple example of what a transfer's balance transaction data might look like:

```
{
  "id": "txn_1MiN3gLkdIwHu7ixxapQrznl",
  "object": "balance_transaction",
  "amount": -400,
  "available_on": 1678043844,
  "created": 1678043844,
  "currency": "usd",
  "description": null,
  "exchange_rate": null,
  "fee": 0,
  "fee_details": [],
  "net": -400,
  "reporting_category": "transfer",
  "source": "tr_1MiN3gLkdIwHu7ixNCZvFdgA",
  "status": "available",
  "type": "transfer"
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically identify which transfers are part of a given payout using Stripe's API. I'm looking for any tips, API endpoints, or strategies to help match transfers to their payouts since Stripe doesn't directly link them.

As a potential solution, I'm considering using the Stripe API to get balance transactions by payout ID and then filter out the transfers:

```
async function getTransactionsForPayout() {
  try {
    const transactions = await stripe.balanceTransactions.list({
      limit: 10,
      payout: payoutId,
    });
    const transferIds = transactions
        .filter(tx => tx.type === 'transfer' && tx.source.startsWith('tr_'))
        .map(tx => tx.source);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching transactions for payout:', error);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the best way to approach this case ( from scalability POV and multiple API calls I'll need to make for each payout).

Any advice or insights would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using an automatic payout, you can see the charges/transfers included in the payout by retrieving the [List All Balance Transactions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list) and [expanding](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) the [source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-source) of the property. This will give you the transfer/ charge ids you’re looking for on the payout. They document this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/expand/use-cases#charges-in-payout) with a sample code. Otherwise, you'd need to track this on your end.

Comment: no, I'm using manual payouts, I don't think this is possible for the manual payouts

Comment: With manual payouts, you would need to track this on your end by adding metadata for instance.

Comment: could you please advise how? do I include metadata when I create transfer? ( will it be available in metadata when I retrieve balance? or initiate payout?)

Comment: You need to track the payment history on your own, you can have a naming/ coding convention on how you track this, then add the metadata on the object. Note that metadata is not transferred between objects.